# Sort Hashtable and assign it to a new variable in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to know how to assign a sorted hasttable using the following command to a new variable. I am using the following command

```
$ht =   @{ 
           1 = "Data1"; 
           3 = "Data3"; 
           2 = "Data2"; 
         }

$htSorted = $ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name
```

but after running it i can't traverse on the resultant hashtable

```
foreach($key in $htSorted.Keys)
{
     $item[$key]
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Works for me. What does "it does not seem to be working" mean?

Comment: sorry stej my bad.. my main problem is that i can not traverse the resultant hastable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you need to have a sorted hashtable, you can use `SortedDictionary`. 
Example:

```
$s = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[int, string]'
1..20 | % { 
  $i = (Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 100)
  write-host $i
  $s[$i] = $i.ToString() 
}
$s
```

I created 20 random values and stored them in the dictionary. Then when PowerShell is going through the dictionary (via `GetEnumerator()`), the values are sorted by keys.

It will be probably much faster than using old hashtable and sorting via `Sort-Object`.

Comment: brilliant! Could you take a look at this as well plz http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658759/assigning-an-array-to-a-dictionary-entry-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

After running `$htSorted.GetType()` and `$htSorted | GetMembers`, It turns out that the  Sort-Object  cmdlet returns an arrary of dictionary entries. Hence i can travers it simply as follows:

```
foreach($item in $htSorted)
{
     $item.Key
     $item.Value    
}
```

Comment: +1. Important to understand here is: Hashtables have no order on the entries; by their very definition they have not. And the result of the sort is no longer a hashtable.

Comment: if you do the following: ```$this.HyperVHosts.Clone().GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value -Descending```
you will get an array of Dictinary Entries. But you can group them back into a hashtable liks so:
 ```$this.HyperVHosts.Clone().GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value -Descending | Group-Object -AsHashTable```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to the OP:

You are setting up the sorted "hashtable" correctly but then you write:

---

```
foreach($key in $htSorted.Keys)
{
     $item[$key]
}
```

---

In order to iterate through the sorted "hashtable" please use the following code:

---

```
foreach($item in $htSorted.GetEnumerator())
{
     write-host $item.key
     write-host $item.value
}
```

As I also heard that a sorted hastable by nature cannot exist, I don't know what kind of object this is after putting it through the sort-object. But at least it behaves just like a sorted hashtable :-)