# Assigning an array to a dictionary entry in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to assign an array as a value to a dictionary entry as follows but its throwing exception.

```
$sd = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[int, string[]]'
$sd[0] = "Data1a", "asda";
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use cast to `[string[]]`:

```
$sd = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[int, string[]]'
$sd[0] = [string[]]("Data1a", "asda")
```

Another options is to change the dictionary value type to `object[]`:

```
$sd = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary[int, object[]]'
$sd[0] = "Data1a", "asda"
```

Comment: brilliant!...i tried casting like u mentioned but i was missing the round brackets. Thanks

Comment: Works great. I like the 2nd snippet much more.

Casting is dirt :D